# Make one group of input fields required of 5 groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

This is the case:

I have **5 groups** of **3 input fields**, so **15** input fields in total. This is how it looks in html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Lower secondary studies</legend>
    <em>Last obtained degree</em>

    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.lwsdegreeTitle" placeholder="Degree title" name="lwsappdegreetitle" id="lwsappdegreetitle" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.lwseducationauthority" placeholder="Education authority" name="lwsappeducationauthority" id="lwsappeducationauthority" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.lwsgraduationyear" placeholder="Graduation year" name="lwsappgraduationyear" id="lwsappgraduationyear" type="text">

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Higher secondary studies</legend>
    <em>Last obtained degree</em>

    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hssdegreeTitle" placeholder="Degree title" name="hssappdegreetitle" id="hssappdegreetitle" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hsseducationauthority" placeholder="Education authority" name="hssappeducationauthority" id="hssappeducationauthority" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hssgraduationyear" placeholder="Graduation year" name="hssappgraduationyear" id="hssappgraduationyear" type="text">

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Higher short term education</legend>
    <em>Last obtained degree</em>

    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hstedegreeTitle" placeholder="Degree title" name="hsteappdegreetitle" id="hsteappdegreetitle" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hsteeducationauthority" placeholder="Education authority" name="hsteappeducationauthority" id="hsteappeducationauthority" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hstegraduationyear" placeholder="Graduation year" name="hsteappgraduationyear" id="hsteappgraduationyear" type="text">

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Higher long term education</legend>
    <em>Last obtained degree</em>

    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hltedegreeTitle" placeholder="Degree title" name="hlteappdegreetitle" id="hlteappdegreetitle" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hlteeducationauthority" placeholder="Education authority" name="hlteappeducationauthority" id="hlteappeducationauthority" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.hltegraduationyear" placeholder="Graduation year" name="hlteappgarduationyear" id="hlteappgraduationyear" type="text">

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Additional studies - specialty</legend>
    <em>Last obtained degree</em>

    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.assdegreeTitle" placeholder="Degree title" name="assappdegreetitle" id="assappdegreetitle" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.asseducationauthority" placeholder="Education authority" name="assappeducationauthority" id="assappeducationauthority" type="text">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="application.assgraduationyear" placeholder="Graduation year" name="assappgarduationyear" id="assappgraduationyear" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Now, how can I make sure that one of the 5 input groups must be filled in (all 3 of the input fields)? So, you can't fill in one of the 3, you have to fill in all 3 of the input fields (of a group).

Comment: Is it valid for one complete all 3 fields of *more than one* input group?

Comment: yes, that can be an option

Answer (score 0):

```
function check() {
    var check = false;
    $.each($('fieldset'), function () { //loops through all fieldsets
        if (!check) { //are there no fieldsets with  3 filled input elements then check is false so far
            check = $(this).find('input:text').filter(function () { //checks whether inputs are filled
                return this.value != "";
            }).length > 2; //If filled inputs > 2 -> check = true
        }
    });
    return check;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english ;-)

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dj5m20ht/)

Comment: And how could I do this if the third field was a number input field instead of a text field?

Comment: Use `$(this).find('input:text,[type^="number"]')` as selector

Answer (score 0):

A very crude (quick and somewhat dirty) solution to make sure that either none or all inputs in a "group" are filled-in is (just keeping the essential parts of a simplified HTML for clarity):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>...</legend>
    <em>...</em>

    <input ng-model="application.a" ng-required="application.b || application.c" />
    <input ng-model="application.b" ng-required="application.a || application.c" />
    <input ng-model="application.c" ng-required="application.b || application.a" />

</fieldset>
```

Meaning: *"each is required if any of the other two has text"*.

If you want more thorough, model based validation, you may want to look at a library I wrote and I am using, [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron).